# Push mail API for receiving mails

Tags: push-notification

I would like to know if there is an API which can receive push notifications for an email client.

Use Case: I would like the server to send my web service notifications on new email. I would not like to poll the server. I would like the server to send notification (PUSH) to the web application.

Also, what are the (if any) mail servers that support this kind of API?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Cloudmailin which is a SAS that will do REST post back to your server